# Porting Jboss/Seam App to newer versions

Tags: jboss, seam, migrate

I have a Web App running using SEAM 2.0.2 on JBoss 4.2. When I tried to run it using Seam 2.1 and JBoss 5, all sorts of problems arised. Is there a porting guide available for this scenario that you're aware of ?

Thanks.

Comment: Which particular problems? Perhaps people here know to solve them.

Answer (score 1):

Start with `jboss-seam-2.1.2/seam21migration.txt` for Seam. I don't know about JBoss 5.